# Create complex class with factory and builder

Tags: oop, design-patterns, class-design, class-diagram

background:
I build a class diagram for shopping on the net.
For creating a user interface with tow type (golden-User and silver-User) I use the factory pattern.
But the User class become to be very complex.

How can I create this class by bulider and on the other hand the ability to specify the user type such as the factory will remain on the class name
(will help me to recognize which type is by polymorphism and not by if&else)

Comment: Can you include sample code for how client code would call such a factory/builder, a more precise description of where the problem lies and what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Decorator pattern is a simple solution:

```html
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User silverUser = new UserDecorator(new SilverUser("Kyriakos", "Georgiopoulos"));
        User goldenUser = new UserDecorator(new GoldenUser("GoldenUser firstName", "GoldenUser lastName"));
        User nullUser = new UserDecorator(null);

        System.out.println(silverUser.firstName() + " " + silverUser.lastName() + " is " + silverUser.type());
        System.out.println(goldenUser.firstName() + " " + goldenUser.lastName() + " is " + goldenUser.type());
        System.out.println(nullUser.firstName() + " " + nullUser.lastName() + " is " + nullUser.type());
         }
}

interface User {
    String firstName();

    String lastName();

    String type();
}

class SilverUser implements User {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    SilverUser(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String firstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String lastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String type() {
        return "SilverUser ";
    }
}

class GoldenUser implements User {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    GoldenUser(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String firstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String lastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String type() {
        return "GoldenUser ";
    }
}

class UserDecorator implements User {
    private final User user;
    
    UserDecorator(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    public String firstName() {
        return user != null && user.firstName() != null && user.firstName().length() > 0 ?
                user.firstName() : "";
    }

    public String lastName() {
        return user != null && user.lastName() != null && user.lastName().length() > 0 ?
                user.lastName() : "";
    }
    
    public String type() {
        return user != null ? user.type() : "NullPointerException";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you're not supposed to use Factory to create different instances of the same class. It can be used to create different implementations of one common abstraction. Try implementing IUser interface. Then implement this interface by two classes: GoldenUser and SilverUser. Your Factory will create instance of either GoldenUser or SilverUser and return it as IUser. Also instead of interface IUser you could probably create User abstract class, that will be inherited by GoldenUser and SilverUser.

Answer (score 0):

The intent of the two patterns are different: while Factory creates an object instance (which can hold more other class instances) the Builder's goal is to create object step-by-step and reduce overloaded constructors.
For example (with java snippets):

**Factory method**

interface for user:

```
public interface User {
}
```

GoldUser class:

```
class GoldUser implements User {
  // ... field declarations
  // Ctor
  GoldUser(fields...){}
  // ... methods 
}
```

SilverUser class:

```
class SilverUser implement User {
  // ... field declarations
  // Ctor
  SilverUser(fields...){}
  // ... methods 
}
```

User Factory Class:

```
public class UserFactory {
  // ... user versions
  public static int GoldUser = 0;
  public static int SilverUser = 1;

  // ... private Ctor because we don't want to instantiate this class - only in this example
  private UserFactory (){}

  // ... creating appropriate User instance
  public static User createUser(int userType){
     switch (userType){
        case GoldUser: return new GoldUser;
        case SilverUser: return new SilverUser;
        default throw new WrongUserTypeException("Wrong User Type");
     }
  }
}
```

in your other class:

```
// ... code stuff here
User user=UserFactory.createUser(1); // will return new SilverUser instance
// ... other code stuff here
```

**Builder pattern**

If you have many fields in your class and only some of them are compulsory, you don't have to create many constructors, a builder will enough:

```
class UserBuilder{
private static Service_A serviceA;  // required
private static Service_B serviceB;  // required
private static Service_C serviceC;
private static Service_D serviceD;
private static Service_E serviceE;

// since this builder is singleton
private static UserBuilder builderInstance = new UserBuilder();
private UserBuilder () {};

public static UserBuilder getBuilderInstance (Service_A service_A, Service_B service_B){
serviceA = service_A;
serviceB = service_B;
serviceC = null; 
serviceD = null;
serviceE = null;
return builderInstance;
}

public static UserBuilder addServiceC (Service_C service_C) {
  serviceC = service_C;
  return builderInstance; 
}

public static UserBuilder addServiceD (Service_D service_D) {
  serviceC = service_D;
  return builderInstance; 
}

public static UserBuilder addServiceE (Service_E service_E) {
  serviceE = service_E;
  return builderInstance; 
}

public static User build(){
  return new User (serviceA, ServiceB, ServiceC, ServiceD, ServiceE);
}
```

And later you can build a customized User:

```
UserBuilder aUserBuilder = UserBuilder.getBuilderInstance(aServiceA, aServiceB);
// ... other stuff
    aUserBuilder.addServiceE(aServiceE);
///... more stuff
 User aUser= aUSerBuilder.addServiceC(aServiceC)
    .build(); // will return the fresh built User instance
```

Hope I could help you!
Regards,
Cs